# Python - cumulative sum up to a certain threshold

Tags: python, pandas, threshold, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe named df_sorted (as in belows image).

What I need is a cumulative sum of `df_sorted['turnover']` grouped by `df_sorted['year_week']` that meets the following condition:

```
df_sorted['kg_cum'] < df_sorted['kg_cum_year_week_20%']
```

The answer based on the image should be a turnover of around 104012

Since I'm relatively new to python I would love to hear on how to solve this.

Feel free to ask for more information if above wasn't clear enough.

Herewith the data as dict:

```
{'orderline': {0: 1418863,
  1: 1418860,
  2: 1418718,
  3: 1418864,
  4: 1418745,
  5: 1418862,
  6: 1418707,
  7: 1418738,
  8: 1418699,
  9: 1418853,
  10: 1418722,
  11: 1418739,
  12: 1418724,
  13: 1418763,
  14: 1418876,
  15: 1418851,
  16: 1418761,
  17: 1418710,
  18: 1418777,
  19: 1418903,
  20: 1418902,
  21: 1418901,
  22: 1418852,
  23: 1418703,
  24: 1418858,
  25: 1418702,
  26: 1418857,
  27: 1418896,
  28: 1418781,
  29: 1418741,
  30: 1418883,
  31: 1418740,
  32: 1418734,
  33: 1418753,
  34: 1418890,
  35: 1418726,
  36: 1418882,
  37: 1418744,
  38: 1418752,
  39: 1418885,
  40: 1418894,
  41: 1418889,
  42: 1418749,
  43: 1418879,
  44: 1418886,
  45: 1418729,
  46: 1418732,
  47: 1418751,
  48: 1418895,
  49: 1418730,
  50: 1418878,
  51: 1418694,
  52: 1418849,
  53: 1418717,
  54: 1419013,
  55: 1418941,
  56: 1419015,
  57: 1418926,
  58: 1419194,
  59: 1418979,
  60: 1419014,
  61: 1419060,
  62: 1419063,
  63: 1419172,
  64: 1419217,
  65: 1419368,
  66: 1418965,
  67: 1419085,
  68: 1419216,
  69: 1419329,
  70: 1418917,
  71: 1419109,
  72: 1418930,
  73: 1419075},
 'year_week': {0: '2019-01',
  1: '2019-01',
  2: '2019-01',
  3: '2019-01',
  4: '2019-01',
  5: '2019-01',
  6: '2019-01',
  7: '2019-01',
  8: '2019-01',
  9: '2019-01',
  10: '2019-01',
  11: '2019-01',
  12: '2019-01',
  13: '2019-01',
  14: '2019-01',
  15: '2019-01',
  16: '2019-01',
  17: '2019-01',
  18: '2019-01',
  19: '2019-01',
  20: '2019-01',
  21: '2019-01',
  22: '2019-01',
  23: '2019-01',
  24: '2019-01',
  25: '2019-01',
  26: '2019-01',
  27: '2019-01',
  28: '2019-01',
  29: '2019-01',
  30: '2019-01',
  31: '2019-01',
  32: '2019-01',
  33: '2019-01',
  34: '2019-01',
  35: '2019-01',
  36: '2019-01',
  37: '2019-01',
  38: '2019-01',
  39: '2019-01',
  40: '2019-01',
  41: '2019-01',
  42: '2019-01',
  43: '2019-01',
  44: '2019-01',
  45: '2019-01',
  46: '2019-01',
  47: '2019-01',
  48: '2019-01',
  49: '2019-01',
  50: '2019-01',
  51: '2019-01',
  52: '2019-01',
  53: '2019-01',
  54: '2019-02',
  55: '2019-02',
  56: '2019-02',
  57: '2019-02',
  58: '2019-02',
  59: '2019-02',
  60: '2019-02',
  61: '2019-02',
  62: '2019-02',
  63: '2019-02',
  64: '2019-02',
  65: '2019-02',
  66: '2019-02',
  67: '2019-02',
  68: '2019-02',
  69: '2019-02',
  70: '2019-02',
  71: '2019-02',
  72: '2019-02',
  73: '2019-02'},
 'kg_orderline': {0: 39600.0,
  1: 1200.0,
  2: 6240.0,
  3: 10200.0,
  4: 19800.0,
  5: 19800.0,
  6: 7200.0,
  7: 6600.0,
  8: 9000.0,
  9: 9000.0,
  10: 12600.0,
  11: 4200.0,
  12: 19800.0,
  13: 1200.0,
  14: 19800.0,
  15: 3600.0,
  16: 3000.0,
  17: 19800.0,
  18: 6600.0,
  19: 1200.0,
  20: 19800.0,
  21: 3000.0,
  22: 10200.0,
  23: 5846.4,
  24: 7308.0,
  25: 2923.2,
  26: 1044.0,
  27: 3000.0,
  28: 4320.0,
  29: 8991.36,
  30: 261.0,
  31: 870.0,
  32: 19800.0,
  33: 16484.16,
  34: 4495.68,
  35: 7992.32,
  36: 2396.8,
  37: 19800.0,
  38: 19800.0,
  39: 19800.0,
  40: 19800.0,
  41: 11504.64,
  42: 8960.0,
  43: 3920.0,
  44: 5600.0,
  45: 8400.0,
  46: 10080.0,
  47: 18480.0,
  48: 6720.0,
  49: 14520.0,
  50: 16720.0,
  51: 15840.0,
  52: 15840.0,
  53: 5200.0,
  54: 19800.0,
  55: 19800.0,
  56: 19800.0,
  57: 5200.0,
  58: 7800.0,
  59: 12000.0,
  60: 12000.0,
  61: 19800.0,
  62: 7800.0,
  63: 19800.0,
  64: 19800.0,
  65: 31200.0,
  66: 19800.0,
  67: 19800.0,
  68: 19800.0,
  69: 19800.0,
  70: 6000.0,
  71: 6000.0,
  72: 19800.0,
  73: 19800.0},
 'Price': {0: 0.743472,
  1: 0.877065,
  2: 0.896822,
  3: 0.899015,
  4: 0.900508,
  5: 0.900508,
  6: 1.011472,
  7: 1.011472,
  8: 1.015272,
  9: 1.015272,
  10: 1.110932,
  11: 1.110932,
  12: 1.111472,
  13: 1.111472,
  14: 1.111472,
  15: 1.115272,
  16: 1.160932,
  17: 1.161472,
  18: 1.161472,
  19: 1.161472,
  20: 1.190932,
  21: 1.191472,
  22: 1.215272,
  23: 1.21580229885057,
  24: 1.21580229885057,
  25: 1.27547126436782,
  26: 1.27588122605364,
  27: 1.311472,
  28: 1.34901875,
  29: 1.34937892376682,
  30: 1.37190114942529,
  31: 1.37320459770115,
  32: 1.377472,
  33: 1.39461434977578,
  34: 1.39461434977578,
  35: 1.39870627802691,
  36: 1.41605841121495,
  37: 1.456678,
  38: 1.456678,
  39: 1.456678,
  40: 1.456678,
  41: 1.46319626168224,
  42: 1.480638,
  43: 1.480638,
  44: 1.480638,
  45: 1.500638,
  46: 1.500638,
  47: 1.500638,
  48: 1.500638,
  49: 1.515914,
  50: 1.515914,
  51: 1.516132,
  52: 1.516132,
  53: 1.516353,
  54: 1.059765,
  55: 1.076573,
  56: 1.077065,
  57: 1.096822,
  58: 1.096822,
  59: 1.098558,
  60: 1.099015,
  61: 1.099015,
  62: 1.099015,
  63: 1.099015,
  64: 1.099015,
  65: 1.099015,
  66: 1.100508,
  67: 1.100508,
  68: 1.100508,
  69: 1.100508,
  70: 1.130932,
  71: 1.135272,
  72: 1.147472,
  73: 1.147472},
 'kg_cum': {0: 39600.0,
  1: 40800.0,
  2: 47040.0,
  3: 57240.0,
  4: 77040.0,
  5: 96840.0,
  6: 104040.0,
  7: 110640.0,
  8: 119640.0,
  9: 128640.0,
  10: 141240.0,
  11: 145440.0,
  12: 165240.0,
  13: 166440.0,
  14: 186240.0,
  15: 189840.0,
  16: 192840.0,
  17: 212640.0,
  18: 219240.0,
  19: 220440.0,
  20: 240240.0,
  21: 243240.0,
  22: 253440.0,
  23: 259286.4,
  24: 266594.4,
  25: 269517.60000000003,
  26: 270561.60000000003,
  27: 273561.60000000003,
  28: 277881.60000000003,
  29: 286872.96,
  30: 287133.96,
  31: 288003.96,
  32: 307803.96,
  33: 324288.12,
  34: 328783.8,
  35: 336776.12,
  36: 339172.92,
  37: 358972.92,
  38: 378772.92,
  39: 398572.92,
  40: 418372.92,
  41: 429877.56,
  42: 438837.56,
  43: 442757.56,
  44: 448357.56,
  45: 456757.56,
  46: 466837.56,
  47: 485317.56,
  48: 492037.56,
  49: 506557.56,
  50: 523277.56,
  51: 539117.56,
  52: 554957.56,
  53: 560157.56,
  54: 19800.0,
  55: 39600.0,
  56: 59400.0,
  57: 64600.0,
  58: 72400.0,
  59: 84400.0,
  60: 96400.0,
  61: 116200.0,
  62: 124000.0,
  63: 143800.0,
  64: 163600.0,
  65: 194800.0,
  66: 214600.0,
  67: 234400.0,
  68: 254200.0,
  69: 274000.0,
  70: 280000.0,
  71: 286000.0,
  72: 305800.0,
  73: 325600.0},
 'kg_cum_year_week': {0: 560157.56,
  1: 560157.56,
  2: 560157.56,
  3: 560157.56,
  4: 560157.56,
  5: 560157.56,
  6: 560157.56,
  7: 560157.56,
  8: 560157.56,
  9: 560157.56,
  10: 560157.56,
  11: 560157.56,
  12: 560157.56,
  13: 560157.56,
  14: 560157.56,
  15: 560157.56,
  16: 560157.56,
  17: 560157.56,
  18: 560157.56,
  19: 560157.56,
  20: 560157.56,
  21: 560157.56,
  22: 560157.56,
  23: 560157.56,
  24: 560157.56,
  25: 560157.56,
  26: 560157.56,
  27: 560157.56,
  28: 560157.56,
  29: 560157.56,
  30: 560157.56,
  31: 560157.56,
  32: 560157.56,
  33: 560157.56,
  34: 560157.56,
  35: 560157.56,
  36: 560157.56,
  37: 560157.56,
  38: 560157.56,
  39: 560157.56,
  40: 560157.56,
  41: 560157.56,
  42: 560157.56,
  43: 560157.56,
  44: 560157.56,
  45: 560157.56,
  46: 560157.56,
  47: 560157.56,
  48: 560157.56,
  49: 560157.56,
  50: 560157.56,
  51: 560157.56,
  52: 560157.56,
  53: 560157.56,
  54: 1567901.1299999997,
  55: 1567901.1299999997,
  56: 1567901.1299999997,
  57: 1567901.1299999997,
  58: 1567901.1299999997,
  59: 1567901.1299999997,
  60: 1567901.1299999997,
  61: 1567901.1299999997,
  62: 1567901.1299999997,
  63: 1567901.1299999997,
  64: 1567901.1299999997,
  65: 1567901.1299999997,
  66: 1567901.1299999997,
  67: 1567901.1299999997,
  68: 1567901.1299999997,
  69: 1567901.1299999997,
  70: 1567901.1299999997,
  71: 1567901.1299999997,
  72: 1567901.1299999997,
  73: 1567901.1299999997},
 'kg_cum_year_week_20%': {0: 112031.51200000002,
  1: 112031.51200000002,
  2: 112031.51200000002,
  3: 112031.51200000002,
  4: 112031.51200000002,
  5: 112031.51200000002,
  6: 112031.51200000002,
  7: 112031.51200000002,
  8: 112031.51200000002,
  9: 112031.51200000002,
  10: 112031.51200000002,
  11: 112031.51200000002,
  12: 112031.51200000002,
  13: 112031.51200000002,
  14: 112031.51200000002,
  15: 112031.51200000002,
  16: 112031.51200000002,
  17: 112031.51200000002,
  18: 112031.51200000002,
  19: 112031.51200000002,
  20: 112031.51200000002,
  21: 112031.51200000002,
  22: 112031.51200000002,
  23: 112031.51200000002,
  24: 112031.51200000002,
  25: 112031.51200000002,
  26: 112031.51200000002,
  27: 112031.51200000002,
  28: 112031.51200000002,
  29: 112031.51200000002,
  30: 112031.51200000002,
  31: 112031.51200000002,
  32: 112031.51200000002,
  33: 112031.51200000002,
  34: 112031.51200000002,
  35: 112031.51200000002,
  36: 112031.51200000002,
  37: 112031.51200000002,
  38: 112031.51200000002,
  39: 112031.51200000002,
  40: 112031.51200000002,
  41: 112031.51200000002,
  42: 112031.51200000002,
  43: 112031.51200000002,
  44: 112031.51200000002,
  45: 112031.51200000002,
  46: 112031.51200000002,
  47: 112031.51200000002,
  48: 112031.51200000002,
  49: 112031.51200000002,
  50: 112031.51200000002,
  51: 112031.51200000002,
  52: 112031.51200000002,
  53: 112031.51200000002,
  54: 313580.22599999997,
  55: 313580.22599999997,
  56: 313580.22599999997,
  57: 313580.22599999997,
  58: 313580.22599999997,
  59: 313580.22599999997,
  60: 313580.22599999997,
  61: 313580.22599999997,
  62: 313580.22599999997,
  63: 313580.22599999997,
  64: 313580.22599999997,
  65: 313580.22599999997,
  66: 313580.22599999997,
  67: 313580.22599999997,
  68: 313580.22599999997,
  69: 313580.22599999997,
  70: 313580.22599999997,
  71: 313580.22599999997,
  72: 313580.22599999997,
  73: 313580.22599999997},
 'turnover': {0: 29441.4912,
  1: 1052.478,
  2: 5596.16928,
  3: 9169.953,
  4: 17830.058399999998,
  5: 17830.058399999998,
  6: 7282.5984,
  7: 6675.7152,
  8: 9137.448,
  9: 9137.448,
  10: 13997.7432,
  11: 4665.914400000001,
  12: 22007.1456,
  13: 1333.7664,
  14: 22007.1456,
  15: 4014.9792,
  16: 3482.7960000000003,
  17: 22997.1456,
  18: 7665.715200000001,
  19: 1393.7664,
  20: 23580.4536,
  21: 3574.416,
  22: 12395.774399999998,
  23: 7108.066559999971,
  24: 8885.083199999965,
  25: 3728.4576000000116,
  26: 1332.0200000000002,
  27: 3934.4159999999997,
  28: 5827.7609999999995,
  29: 12132.751680000034,
  30: 358.06620000000066,
  31: 1194.6880000000006,
  32: 27273.9456,
  33: 22989.04607999992,
  34: 6269.739839999978,
  35: 11178.908160000032,
  36: 3394.0087999999923,
  37: 28842.2244,
  38: 28842.2244,
  39: 28842.2244,
  40: 28842.2244,
  41: 16833.546239999967,
  42: 13266.516479999998,
  43: 5804.10096,
  44: 8291.5728,
  45: 12605.359199999999,
  46: 15126.43104,
  47: 27731.79024,
  48: 10084.28736,
  49: 22011.07128,
  50: 25346.08208,
  51: 24015.530880000002,
  52: 24015.530880000002,
  53: 7885.0356,
  54: 20983.347,
  55: 21316.1454,
  56: 21325.887,
  57: 5703.4744,
  58: 8555.2116,
  59: 13182.696,
  60: 13188.18,
  61: 21760.497000000003,
  62: 8572.317000000001,
  63: 21760.497000000003,
  64: 21760.497000000003,
  65: 34289.268000000004,
  66: 21790.0584,
  67: 21790.0584,
  68: 21790.0584,
  69: 21790.0584,
  70: 6785.592000000001,
  71: 6811.6320000000005,
  72: 22719.945600000003,
  73: 22719.945600000003},
 'new_turnover': {0: 29441.4912,
  1: 30493.9692,
  2: 36090.13848,
  3: 45260.09148,
  4: 63090.14988,
  5: 80920.20827999999,
  6: 88202.80668,
  7: 94878.52188,
  8: 104015.96988,
  9: nan,
  10: nan,
  11: nan,
  12: nan,
  13: nan,
  14: nan,
  15: nan,
  16: nan,
  17: nan,
  18: nan,
  19: nan,
  20: nan,
  21: nan,
  22: nan,
  23: nan,
  24: nan,
  25: nan,
  26: nan,
  27: nan,
  28: nan,
  29: nan,
  30: nan,
  31: nan,
  32: nan,
  33: nan,
  34: nan,
  35: nan,
  36: nan,
  37: nan,
  38: nan,
  39: nan,
  40: nan,
  41: nan,
  42: nan,
  43: nan,
  44: nan,
  45: nan,
  46: nan,
  47: nan,
  48: nan,
  49: nan,
  50: nan,
  51: nan,
  52: nan,
  53: nan,
  54: 124999.31688,
  55: 146315.46228,
  56: 167641.34928,
  57: 173344.82368,
  58: 181900.03528,
  59: 195082.73128,
  60: 208270.91128,
  61: 230031.40828,
  62: 238603.72528,
  63: 260364.22228000002,
  64: 282124.71928,
  65: 316413.98728,
  66: 338204.04568,
  67: 359994.10407999996,
  68: 381784.16247999994,
  69: 403574.2208799999,
  70: 410359.8128799999,
  71: 417171.4448799999,
  72: nan,
  73: nan}}

​
```

[image: df_sorted]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please remember to include your data as text, not images.

Comment: Can you add your data as text, either csv or text, df[0:14].to_dict() or df[0:14].to_csv()

Comment: @oppressionslayer how can I add a csv? It's my first time at stackoverflow

Comment: Those commands above give a text output that we can then create a dataframe from, it helps for testing to make sure our answer works with your DF.

Comment: @oppressionslayer i posted the dict. Is this the right way of posting it?

Comment: That works, i can read it in now, thx!

Comment: Ok great i figured "```" would do the trick

Comment: The answer i got was one value short of what your looking for due to kg_cum being greater than kg_cum_year...  Did you need that value as well?

Comment: If possible yes please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this is the output your looking for, lmk:

```
new_df = df_sorted.groupby('year_week')['turnover'].cumsum() 
df_sorted['new_turnover'] = new_df[new_df <  df_sorted['kg_cum_year_week_20%']]
```

output:

```
    orderline year_week  kg_orderline     Price     kg_cum  kg_cum_year_week  kg_cum_year_week_20%     turnover  turnover_20%  new_turnover
0     1418863   2019-01      39600.00  0.743472   39600.00         560157.56            112031.512  29441.49120   29441.49120   29441.49120
1     1418860   2019-01       1200.00  0.877065   40800.00         560157.56            112031.512   1052.47800   30493.96920   30493.96920
2     1418718   2019-01       6240.00  0.896822   47040.00         560157.56            112031.512   5596.16928   36090.13848   36090.13848
3     1418864   2019-01      10200.00  0.899015   57240.00         560157.56            112031.512   9169.95300   45260.09148   45260.09148
4     1418745   2019-01      19800.00  0.900508   77040.00         560157.56            112031.512  17830.05840   63090.14988   63090.14988
5     1418862   2019-01      19800.00  0.900508   96840.00         560157.56            112031.512  17830.05840   80920.20828   80920.20828
6     1418707   2019-01       7200.00  1.011472  104040.00         560157.56            112031.512   7282.59840   88202.80668   88202.80668
7     1418738   2019-01       6600.00  1.011472  110640.00         560157.56            112031.512   6675.71520   94878.52188   94878.52188
8     1418699   2019-01       9000.00  1.015272  119640.00         560157.56            112031.512   9137.44800           NaN  104015.96988
9     1418853   2019-01       9000.00  1.015272  128640.00         560157.56            112031.512   9137.44800           NaN           NaN
10    1418722   2019-01      12600.00  1.110932  141240.00         560157.56            112031.512  13997.74320           NaN           NaN
11    1418739   2019-01       4200.00  1.110932  145440.00         560157.56            112031.512   4665.91440           NaN           NaN
12    1418724   2019-01      19800.00  1.111472  165240.00         560157.56            112031.512  22007.14560           NaN           NaN
13    1418763   2019-01       1200.00  1.111472  166440.00         560157.56            112031.512   1333.76640           NaN           NaN
14    1418876   2019-01      19800.00  1.111472  186240.00         560157.56            112031.512  22007.14560           NaN           NaN
15    1418851   2019-01       3600.00  1.115272  189840.00         560157.56            112031.512   4014.97920           NaN           NaN
16    1418761   2019-01       3000.00  1.160932  192840.00         560157.56            112031.512   3482.79600           NaN           NaN
17    1418710   2019-01      19800.00  1.161472  212640.00         560157.56            112031.512  22997.14560           NaN           NaN
18    1418777   2019-01       6600.00  1.161472  219240.00         560157.56            112031.512   7665.71520           NaN           NaN
19    1418903   2019-01       1200.00  1.161472  220440.00         560157.56            112031.512   1393.76640           NaN           NaN
20    1418902   2019-01      19800.00  1.190932  240240.00         560157.56            112031.512  23580.45360           NaN           NaN
21    1418901   2019-01       3000.00  1.191472  243240.00         560157.56            112031.512   3574.41600           NaN           NaN
22    1418852   2019-01      10200.00  1.215272  253440.00         560157.56            112031.512  12395.77440           NaN           NaN
23    1418703   2019-01       5846.40  1.215802  259286.40         560157.56            112031.512   7108.06656           NaN           NaN
24    1418858   2019-01       7308.00  1.215802  266594.40         560157.56            112031.512   8885.08320           NaN           NaN
25    1418702   2019-01       2923.20  1.275471  269517.60         560157.56            112031.512   3728.45760           NaN           NaN
26    1418857   2019-01       1044.00  1.275881  270561.60         560157.56            112031.512   1332.02000           NaN           NaN
27    1418896   2019-01       3000.00  1.311472  273561.60         560157.56            112031.512   3934.41600           NaN           NaN
28    1418781   2019-01       4320.00  1.349019  277881.60         560157.56            112031.512   5827.76100           NaN           NaN
29    1418741   2019-01       8991.36  1.349379  286872.96         560157.56            112031.512  12132.75168           NaN           NaN
30    1418883   2019-01        261.00  1.371901  287133.96         560157.56            112031.512    358.06620           NaN           NaN
31    1418740   2019-01        870.00  1.373205  288003.96         560157.56            112031.512   1194.68800           NaN           NaN
32    1418734   2019-01      19800.00  1.377472  307803.96         560157.56            112031.512  27273.94560           NaN           NaN
33    1418753   2019-01      16484.16  1.394614  324288.12         560157.56            112031.512  22989.04608           NaN           NaN
34    1418890   2019-01       4495.68  1.394614  328783.80         560157.56            112031.512   6269.73984           NaN           NaN
35    1418726   2019-01       7992.32  1.398706  336776.12         560157.56            112031.512  11178.90816           NaN           NaN
36    1418882   2019-01       2396.80  1.416058  339172.92         560157.56            112031.512   3394.00880           NaN           NaN
37    1418744   2019-01      19800.00  1.456678  358972.92         560157.56            112031.512  28842.22440           NaN           NaN
38    1418752   2019-01      19800.00  1.456678  378772.92         560157.56            112031.512  28842.22440           NaN           NaN
39    1418885   2019-01      19800.00  1.456678  398572.92         560157.56            112031.512  28842.22440           NaN           NaN
40    1418894   2019-01      19800.00  1.456678  418372.92         560157.56            112031.512  28842.22440           NaN           NaN
41    1418889   2019-01      11504.64  1.463196  429877.56         560157.56            112031.512  16833.54624           NaN           NaN
42    1418749   2019-01       8960.00  1.480638  438837.56         560157.56            112031.512  13266.51648           NaN           NaN
43    1418879   2019-01       3920.00  1.480638  442757.56         560157.56            112031.512   5804.10096           NaN           NaN
44    1418886   2019-01       5600.00  1.480638  448357.56         560157.56            112031.512   8291.57280           NaN           NaN
45    1418729   2019-01       8400.00  1.500638  456757.56         560157.56            112031.512  12605.35920           NaN           NaN
46    1418732   2019-01      10080.00  1.500638  466837.56         560157.56            112031.512  15126.43104           NaN           NaN
47    1418751   2019-01      18480.00  1.500638  485317.56         560157.56            112031.512  27731.79024           NaN           NaN
48    1418895   2019-01       6720.00  1.500638  492037.56         560157.56            112031.512  10084.28736           NaN           NaN
49    1418730   2019-01      14520.00  1.515914  506557.56         560157.56            112031.512  22011.07128           NaN           NaN
50    1418878   2019-01      16720.00  1.515914  523277.56         560157.56            112031.512  25346.08208           NaN           NaN
51    1418694   2019-01      15840.00  1.516132  539117.56         560157.56            112031.512  24015.53088           NaN           NaN
52    1418849   2019-01      15840.00  1.516132  554957.56         560157.56            112031.512  24015.53088           NaN           NaN
53    1418717   2019-01       5200.00  1.516353  560157.56         560157.56            112031.512   7885.03560           NaN           NaN
54    1419013   2019-02      19800.00  1.059765   19800.00        1567901.13            313580.226  20983.34700  115861.86888   20983.34700
55    1418941   2019-02      19800.00  1.076573   39600.00        1567901.13            313580.226  21316.14540  137178.01428   42299.49240
56    1419015   2019-02      19800.00  1.077065   59400.00        1567901.13            313580.226  21325.88700  158503.90128   63625.37940
57    1418926   2019-02       5200.00  1.096822   64600.00        1567901.13            313580.226   5703.47440  164207.37568   69328.85380
58    1419194   2019-02       7800.00  1.096822   72400.00        1567901.13            313580.226   8555.21160  172762.58728   77884.06540
59    1418979   2019-02      12000.00  1.098558   84400.00        1567901.13            313580.226  13182.69600  185945.28328   91066.76140
60    1419014   2019-02      12000.00  1.099015   96400.00        1567901.13            313580.226  13188.18000  199133.46328  104254.94140
61    1419060   2019-02      19800.00  1.099015  116200.00        1567901.13            313580.226  21760.49700  220893.96028  126015.43840
62    1419063   2019-02       7800.00  1.099015  124000.00        1567901.13            313580.226   8572.31700  229466.27728  134587.75540
63    1419172   2019-02      19800.00  1.099015  143800.00        1567901.13            313580.226  21760.49700  251226.77428  156348.25240
64    1419217   2019-02      19800.00  1.099015  163600.00        1567901.13            313580.226  21760.49700  272987.27128  178108.74940
65    1419368   2019-02      31200.00  1.099015  194800.00        1567901.13            313580.226  34289.26800  307276.53928  212398.01740
66    1418965   2019-02      19800.00  1.100508  214600.00        1567901.13            313580.226  21790.05840  329066.59768  234188.07580
67    1419085   2019-02      19800.00  1.100508  234400.00        1567901.13            313580.226  21790.05840  350856.65608  255978.13420
68    1419216   2019-02      19800.00  1.100508  254200.00        1567901.13            313580.226  21790.05840  372646.71448  277768.19260
69    1419329   2019-02      19800.00  1.100508  274000.00        1567901.13            313580.226  21790.05840  394436.77288  299558.25100
70    1418917   2019-02       6000.00  1.130932  280000.00        1567901.13            313580.226   6785.59200  401222.36488  306343.84300
71    1419109   2019-02       6000.00  1.135272  286000.00        1567901.13            313580.226   6811.63200  408033.99688  313155.47500
72    1418930   2019-02      19800.00  1.147472  305800.00        1567901.13            313580.226  22719.94560  430753.94248           NaN
73    1419075   2019-02      19800.00  1.147472  325600.00        1567901.13            313580.226  22719.94560           NaN           NaN
74    1419349   2019-02      19800.00  1.147472  345400.00        1567901.13            313580.226  22719.94560           NaN           NaN
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. How can I reset this pattern for each year_week?

Comment: hmm, what do yo mean by reset?, you can get the next sets answer by adding ~ in front of the comparisons, df_sorted[~(df_sorted['kg_cum'] < df_sorted['kg_cum_year_week_20%']) | ~(df_sorted['kg_cum'] == 119640.00) ].turnover.sum()

Comment: I updated the data so you have data for 2 weeks. It seems the cumulative turnover 20 % does not reset starting a new week

Comment: @Luukv93, can you look at try this, and see if that works for you? you can print the full output with print(df_sorted.to_string())

Comment: unfortunately the turnover does not show the correct value starting from year_week 2019-02    df_sorted.loc[df_sorted['year_week']=='2019-02'] row with index 54: new_turnover shows 124999.31688 instead of 20983.34700

Comment: ok, if will try to figure it out this is a new one for me. Maybe my answer will help others as well to get you the answer you need. it looks like the cumsum needs to start over at the second set

Comment: @Luukv93, i reset the cumsum to restart at the next group, but your turnover 20% is different there, can you let me know how you get the starting number. Can you look at my updated answer

Comment: Big thanks, hero! This works and i'm amazed by the outcomes!

Comment: I did but since my reputation is below 15 it doesn't show the score. Thanks once again!

Comment: @Luukv93 Check this document out: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235